# GRANT CONTROL on DATABASE::master fails

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm logged in with the user that is marked in the Azure portal as being the server admin.
I need to grant control database to a given user so that the sys.fn_get_audit_file can be executed.

But even with the admin user I'm getting the error

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CONTROL permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using correct authentication. E.g. Windows, Azure etc.

Also be sure you have permission to create database

Run below query on you database

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER your-user;  
GO
```

Refer this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78388/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-unable-to-get-the-permis) for more information.